# SQLException: Access denied in Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a Bitnami Tomcat server with MySQL and a Spring Boot application.

When I try to run the application with `./bin/catalina.sh run`, I get the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'person_db_user'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)

Here is the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/persons_db
spring.datasource.username=person_db_user
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.mvc.throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound=true
```

The user exists, and I'm able to access MySQL from the command line with it.

I can't figure out what the problem is does anybody have any idea?

Comment: You might be able to log in to MySQL with the given user but can you access `persons_db`?

Comment: please check the user "privileges" in mysql  ..esp. the "host" column...maybe there's a problem regarding "localhost" vs. "127.0.0.1"... and also *not a good practice*: to use the "root" user! ...there are several threads in bitnami forum regarding "mysql access denied" .. but no "out-of-the box solution"...it seems to be rather an individual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command  can help you: Execute it in command line or some GUI tool.

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'erson_db_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED
>   BY '%password%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Don't forget to replace %password% with real password.

Comment: Thanks that seems to solve the problem, however I had to run FLUSH PRIVILEGES; also.